# Shopify - footer menus (divs) not falling below each other on a mobile?

Tags: html, css, uitableview, shopify, footer

I'm using shopify theme "Supply" and edited my footer code to have 4 menus (divs) instead of 3. But now when I compress my page to see how it looks on a mobile/iPad the footer menus don't fall under each other, they just all squish up inline together.

Do you know how I might fix this please so the footer menus fall under each other but I can have the 4 menus?

My footer now after editing the CSS screenshot: https://postimg.org/image/ssnzk93i7/

I'm using shopify free supply theme: http://supply-electronics.myshopify.com/

I duplicated the code in the 1st footer block to create footer menu 3 (proud to support) and gave it it's own class "large--three-custom" and used a 'snippet', to place where I wanted the new block to go:

`{% include 'custom-snippet.liquid' %}`

I then edited the CSS by adding the following code just before the end head tag `</head>` in theme.liquid:

`{{ 'custom-styles.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}`

and then created a blank custom-styles.css.liquid in Assets where I added the following CSS.

I changed the % values in this CSS code for the footer blocks to fit the width of page (in the original theme with only 3 footer menus they fall under each other fine on a mobile or ipad)

```
/*footer block 1*/
.large--three-twelfths {
width: 21%;
}

/*footer block 2*/
.large--five-twelfths {
width: 23%;
}

/*footer block 3*/
.large--three-custom {
width: 27%;
}


/*footer block 4*/
.large--one-third {
width: 29%;
```

do you know how I might fix this?

Answer (score 0):

There are many cases for this type of issue. 1) html tag not closed properly , 2) jquery conflict , 3) css issue. 
May be for mobile / ipad some script is  not working. 
Check browser’s console tab, May be there is some javascript error.